# What's the most efficient way to implement classes in Lua?

Tags: lua

By efficient, I mean performance wise. If you have to access class members rapidly, like when drawing UI, what is the best way to index them?

My understanding is that table-based classes use less memory and are faster at creating instances, while closure-based classes have faster function calls and let you have private fields which are quickly indexed because they are stored as upvalues. What's the best implementation for a situation like the example class below?

```lua
-- Example of Table-based Class

local class = {}
class.x = 0
class.y = 0
class.w = 0
class.h = 0

-- Draw would be called for potentially dozens of instances many times per second
function class:Draw()
    draw_rect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
end
```

```lua
-- Example of Closure-based class

local function class(_x, _y, _w, _h)
  -- the new instance
  local self = {
    -- public fields
    visible = false
  }

  -- private fields are locals
  local x, y, w, h = _x, _y, _w, _h

  function self.SetPos(_x, _y)
    x = _x
    y = _y
  end

  function self.GetPos()
    return x, y
  end

  function self.GetVisible()
    return self.visible
  end

  -- return the instance
  return self
end

local obj = class(10, 20, 40, 80)
print(obj.GetPos()) --> 10, 20

obj.SetPos(50, 100)
print(obj.GetPos()) --> 50, 100

obj.x = 21
obj.y = 42
print(obj.GetPos())  --> 50, 100 (unchanged, private)

obj.visible = true
print(obj.GetVisible()) -- true (public)
```

Comment: Reading upvalue is significantly faster than indexing a table.  But how to OOP with upvalues only without tables?

Comment: There is no way that function call overhead for UI rendering is going to be your *bottleneck*. Whatever is happening inside of `draw_rect` will take considerably longer than the time it takes to call `class:Draw`, regardless of what method you use.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I added an example of how a closure-based class would work. It seems like this would be the best implementation?

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you think it's not worth worrying about which class implementation I should use then?

Comment: @ghetto: No. You should worry about performance if it becomes a problem, and even then, you should use a profiler to tell you *where* the performance problem actually is, rather than assuming where it will be. The only time you should pre-emptively deal with performance is if you have specific domain knowledge sufficient to tell you up-front that performance *will* be an issue in a particular location.

Comment: @ghetto - Yes, private variables are better to store in upvalues.  Another problem is that closures are created individually for EVERY new object.  It's ok for singletons, but if many objects of the same class are expected, the time spent for creating a new object could be reduced by using a metatable (but indexing through a metatable is more costly than direct indexing).